# How do add value to a map, from a variable in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to add a map to a key in fire-store. Getting `undefined` in console and it is adding a empty map in firetsore.

I am uploading a multiple files at once in storage and getting imageUrls.
`imageUrls={0:0.png,1:1.png}` from this function.

```
const onUploadFiles = async (images) => {
        let imageUrls = {};
        Promise.all(
            images.map(async (image) => {
                const fileRef = storage.ref(`${scanID}/${chapterNumber}/${image.name}`);
                await fileRef.put(image);
                imageUrls[getFileName(image.name)] = await fileRef
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .toString();
                console.log(imageUrls[getFileName(image.name)]);
            })
        );
        return imageUrls;
    };
```

Once the files are uploaded I am trying to add this map to a document and adding it in firestore.

Utitlity function to store the name of the file as key.
  `const getFileName = (name) => name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '');`

Adding these url as a document.

```
    //add chapter to firestore
    const addChapter = async (images) => {
        var chapter = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            title: title,
            chapterNumber: chapterNumber,
        };
        await onUploadFiles(images)
            .then((imageUrls) => {
                chapter['images'] = imageUrls;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Something went wring with database');
            });
        db.collection('chapters')
            .doc(scanID)
            .set(
                {
                    [chapterNumber]: chapter,
                },
                //merge
                { merge: true }
            )
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Done');
            });
    };
```

Expected output:

```
{
   "0":{
      "title":"title 1",
      "id":"232131-321-312-331",
      "chapterNumber":0,
      "images":{
         "0":"0.png",
         "1":"1.png"
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting an empty map `{}` in firestore.

Answer (score 1):

If I’m not misunderstanding, you would like to upload the images first to Firebase Cloud Storage buckets, and then retrieve the download URLs to include them in a document you are creating for a Firestore collection. If that’s the case, then in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60922198/) there is a script that can help you upload images to Firebase Storage. I have tested this script, and it’s working on my test Node environment. Something I noticed from your code and the script I linked is that there is no `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` property that provides a download token for your URLs:

```
const metadata = {
    metadata: {
      // This line is very important. It's to create a download token.
      firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid()
    },
...
```

I have linked a [guide](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens) related to downloading tokens and how to create them and obtain them. Finally, as to how to create Map objects from a variable to add to Firestore, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types) provides an example of an object for Firestore:

```
const data = {
    stringExample: 'Hello, World!',
    booleanExample: true,
    numberExample: 3.14159265,
    dateExample: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('December 10, 1815')),
    arrayExample: [5, true, 'hello'],
    nullExample: null,
    //Map object
    objectExample: {
        a: 5,
        b: true
    }
};
```

Comment: I want to upload the images first and when done,get all the urls and save it in firestore.