# How to upload images on firebase storage using firebase-admin and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I was trying to upload an image into my firebase storage but im getting the error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'child')

This is my code below

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://url.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "mybucket.appspot.com"
});

const dbStorage = admin.storage();

var uploadTask  = dbStorage.bucket().ref('/news').child(key+"/"+image).put(image, metadata);//got an error
```

I was trying to fixed it like

```
dbStorage.bucket.child() //dbStorage.bucket.ref is not a function
dbStorage.bucket().child() //dbStorage.bucket(...).ref is not a function
dbStorage.ref('/news').child() //ref is not a fucntion
```

Answer (score 0):

The `storage` object in the Admin SDKs is a very thin wrapper around the underling GCP SDKs and doesn't have all conveniences that you may be used to from Firebase SDKs, such as (in this case) a `child` method for building a path.

Instead you will have to build the path yourself:

```
await bucket.upload('destination/path/in/bucket', {
  ...
});
```

Also see: [Firebase Storage upload image file from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60923172)

Comment: `no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\FGCI Administrator\Desktop\Systems\admin-incidentReport\incidentReport\path\to\Screenshot 2022-05-19 170024.png']` how i suppose to put the path ? maybe you can provide on how to